# How to convert ascii format of an image to jpeg in react native

Tags: image, react-native

I have ascii format or an byte array of an image. What are the possible ways to convert it into jpeg or jpg format in react native??

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am getting an image in byte array format So, how can I convert this to image ? byte arry= -0.3,-23.599999999999998,-0.11,-9.6,0,1.76,22.2,41.3,8.03,21,-0.59,0.11,0.3,0,0,0.3,0,0.11,0,0,-0.11,-11.1,0,7.37,0,3.54,0.44,1.5,3.54,0.55,1.2,3.54,0.66,1.5,3.54,0.77,2.1,3.54,0.88,3,9.44,1.1,3,5.31,0.99,3,11.799999999999999,1.54,4.5,7.08,1.76,6.8999999999999995,11.799999999999999,2.64,7.199999999999999,13.56999999999999

Comment: First, what's the format of your byte array?

Comment: Its in the form of String or array